# How to styling the all the form elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How to style all the form elements of a web page (including checkbox, radio, file, etc)

If I need to use a jQuery plugin, then which is the best?

Comment: Why jQuery? You can style your form fields with CSS alone (and there are CSS packages for that on the Internet for sure)...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (css) ?

```
form input {
  //your style rules here
}
```

If you really need to do this dynamic, with jQuery you can also do:

```
$('form input').css({ 'color' : 'red' });
```

Or perhaps:

```
$('form input').addClass('my-input');
```

**css:**

```
input.my-input {
  // style rules here.
}
```

Comment: i basically need customised, inputye text, select, checkbox, radio and file items. Eac of them have similar style, like border color, background image etc.. can u suggest..

Comment: Use the first example, the css one. All of those are <inputs> but the dropdown that is a <select>.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form > *")
.css( { prop1: value1, prop2:value2 } );
// here propXXX= any css property like color/margin and valueXXX= any reasonable value for the property
```

Comment: This would style all forms, not all form elements

Comment: @Pablo: right you are. Just inserted `> *` hierarchy, I guess now it will include all the child of form. . .But i am not sure if it is optimized or not than `.child().each( )` strategy

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.css()` of jquery..

```
$('#formId input').css({ 'color' : 'red' });
```

Comment: What i think, These code didnt stylize input type file, select, radio and check boxes